# Different assert results from "same" string

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

I am trying to read a file and assert some .Contains to ensure the correct data is written to file. I have 5 lines i need to assert and thought it would be smart to run through them with a for-loop. But sadly the asserts in the for-loop yield different results than the 5 hardcoded asserts. The code is as follows:

```
string writtenFile = File.ReadAllText(completeFilePathWithNameAndExtension);

Assert.IsTrue(writtenFile.Contains("2000-04-09 08:13:15:015 Test: 1."));
Assert.IsTrue(writtenFile.Contains("2000-04-09 08:13:15:030 Test: 2."));
Assert.IsTrue(writtenFile.Contains("2000-04-09 08:13:15:045 Test: 3."));
Assert.IsTrue(writtenFile.Contains("2000-04-09 08:13:15:060 Test: 4."));

for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
    {

        Assert.IsTrue(writtenFile.Contains(
           "2000-04-09 08:13:15:0" + i*15 + " Test: " + i + "."));
    }

Value of writtenFile: "Timestamp                \tData           \t\r\n2000-04-09 08:13:15:000\tTest: 0. \t\r\n2000-04-09 08:13:15:015\tTest: 1. \t\r\n2000-04-09 08:13:15:030\tTest: 2. \t\r\n2000-04-09 08:13:15:045\tTest: 3. \t\r\n2000-04-09 08:13:15:060\tTest: 4. \t\r\n"
```

I've done so much experimentation and the string seems to be identical in any way possible. I also tried making it String for UTF-16 chars and did not work either. Aditionally i tried making a temp string in the for-loop and assert on that one instead. Same result.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you have just those 4 strings, not more?

Comment: No but i want to show how it can be done more scaleable.

Comment: If you have more, when `i` becomes greater than 6 it will produce incorrect results (like "0105" instead of "105").

Comment: No repro with this data, as expected. .NET strings *are* UTF16. There are no monsters. If the comparisons fail, ti's because the strings are different. What are the *actual* strings that fail? Can you post a *reproducible example*?

Comment: Yea sorry for that, now added the value of writtenFile.

Comment: So you have a "tab" in your literal strings defined in the first 4 lines ? e.g. Assert.IsTrue(writtenFile.Contains("2000-04-09 08:13:15:015(TAB HERE NOT SPACE)Test: 1."));

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Without a tab, both sets of tests fail. *With* a tab, both succeed

Comment: And with tab in one and not in the other ? ... and setting tab width to one space for instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in your example using 4 lines :

```
Assert.IsTrue(writtenFile.Contains("2000-04-09 08:13:15:060 Test: 4."));
```

And now in your loop you're doing :

```
Assert.IsTrue(writtenFile.Contains("2000-04-09 08:13:15:0" + i * 15 + " Test: " + i + "."));
```

This should give you a hint that let's say `10 * 15 == 150` so the string result would be `"2000-04-09 08:13:15:0150\tTest: 10."` and not `"2000-04-09 08:13:15:150\tTest: 10."`.

What you should use is `"2000-04-09 08:13:15:" + ( i * 15 ).ToString("D3") + "\tTest: " + i + "."`.

Comment: Thank you, it works just perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Okay i changed the string to ("2000-04-09 08:13:15:0{0}\tTest: {1}.", k * 15, k) (added the \t between {0} and Test) which makes it work, sadly i still don't udnerstand why the hardcoded assert works without \t.

Comment: In Edit menu, choose Advanced...View White Space.  If you are using TABs, then it will show them as a right pointing arrow. That would be why it worked. You must have "copied" those strings straight from the file, and thus it maintained the TAB when you pasted in. Whereas when you formed your own string you forgot to add the \t.

Comment: No repro. You probably copied the tabs without realizing, because both tests *always* return the same, as long as the strings produced are the same - ie they include tabs

Comment: Also use: ("2000-04-09 08:13:15:{0:D3}\tTest: {1}.", k * 15, k) ....so that k can be any "reasonable" value, and it still creates a correctly formatted string e.g. when k higher than 4.